stubbing Date.today for Minitest
While an application will run methods using the system clock,
testing to time- or date-sensitive methods can get messy.  One could alter fixtures:
such as:
availability_date: <%= Date.today %> in lieu of availability_date: 2024-06-24
However when considering methods that are related N days away from what is normally the current date, this may overload the fixture set, inserting further opportunities of errors (detected or non); it becomes preferable to use a subset of data drawn from a database, where the data is correct and works as epxected.
Is there any way to stub the test's use of the system clock so that it would reflect 2024-06-24 when the actual date is way past that?

travel_to does the stubbing you want - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to

Timecop gem is a useful tool in Ruby for testing time-dependent code. It allows you to "freeze" time, travel to a different point in time(past or future), and manipulate time to test how your code behaves at different moments. For e.g:
Timecop.freeze(Time.local(2020, 12, 25)) do
  puts Time.now          # Outputs 2020-12-25 00:00:00
end

OR
Timecop.freeze(30.days.ago) do
  puts Time.now          # DateTime.now - 30.days
end


dbugger's comment provides the path forward, without adding dependencies.
